# ag-grid: Highlight cells in a row where the value of a particular cell is different to that of the previous row

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I'd like to apply some conditional formatting where each cell of a row is compared to the cell in the previous row.  If it differs then the row is highlighted.

[image: Example of desired output]

I'm using ag-grid in angular js typescript.  Is this even possible?  If so could someone provide me with the steps to apply this to an entire table of data?

Comment: are you going to allow filtering or editing or sorting to occur on the grid?

Comment: What does your row data look like? Is it simply as flat as the example suggests?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the difference highlighting with the following defaultColDef function:

```
  defaultColDef = {
    cellStyle: function(params) {
        const rowIndex = params.node.rowIndex;
        const columnId = params.colDef.field;
           
        const previousRowIndex = rowIndex - 1;
        if(params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(previousRowIndex) === undefined){
          return { 'background-color': null};
        }

        const currentValue = params.value;
        const previousValue = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(previousRowIndex).data[columnId];
       
        if (currentValue !== previousValue) {
          return { 'background-color': 'lightblue' };
        }
  
        return { 'background-color': null};
      }
  }
```

Here is the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-diff-highlighting